# Disabling only the controls on the page using asp.net gridview control

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My dropdownlist is inside the gridview asp.net control and i am disabling the dropdownlist by doing this:

```
 var $myddl = $('select');
 $myddl.prop("disabled", true);
```

but the problem is that its disabling everything that have `select elements` in the entire master page, so in my situation i have two tabs `Tab A` and `Tab B` and how can i disable only the dropdownlist in Tab A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a css class to them to give them a grouping.  For example, all selects in Tab A could have a css class called 'TabA', and Tab B could have a css class called 'TabB':

```
var $myTabASelects = $('select.TabA');
$myTabASelects.prop("disabled", true);

var $myTabBSelects = $('select.TabB');
$myTabBSelects.prop("disabled", true);
```

Or, really, you could just do this assuming only your selects have TabA/TabB css class:

```
var $myTabASelects = $('.TabA');
$myTabASelects.prop("disabled", true);

var $myTabBSelects = $('.TabB');
$myTabBSelects.prop("disabled", true);
```

Here are more ways to 'select' controls: [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: when i say Tab A i was refering to a page an aspx (asp.net)

Comment: This still applies.  The key here is that you provide a special grouping for your dropdowns.  That way, using jQuery you can work with just those dropdowns and not all of them as your code currently does.  You can call the css classes TabA, FooA, Watermelon, or even Onion, it doesn't change a thing...grouping is what you are after.  So, to be clear, add a css class to all dropdowns in your page, but exclude the dropdowns that are in the masterpage.  Then, call one of the above examples using the appropriate css class and you are golden.

Comment: i know i know... i was just trying to be clear in my question.